# Purge varnish cache for a single url using varnishadm

Tags: varnish, cache

Varnish is being used in a Wordpress website.

I would like to purge Varnish for a single URL instead of a whole domain.

With this command I can restart Varnish for the whole domain:

```
varnishadm -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret 'ban req.http.host ~ \"http://www.foo.com\" && req.url ~ \"^/\"'
```

However I would like to purge varnish only for a single url.

Ex: `www.foo.com/url_to_be_purged`

I've tried the previous command replacing it with the single URL:

```
varnishadm -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret 'ban req.http.host ~ \"http://www.foo.com/url_to_be_purged\" && req.url ~ \"^/\"'
```

But it didn't work, the URL still was a `HIT` in Varnish.

Any ideas of how can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

As suggested ghloogh's answer, I've tried the following command:

```
varnishadm -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret ban "req.http.host == http://www.foo.com && req.url == http://www.foo.com/url_to_be_purged"
```

I've also tried this variation:

```
varnishadm -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret ban "req.http.host == http://www.foo.com && req.url == /url_to_be_purged"
```

But I still get a `HIT` in the URL and the data is not updated

Comment: man, stop using scheme (http:// or https:// or ftp:// or other) in hostname :)
your command should be:
varnishadm -T :6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret ban "req.http.host == www.foo.com && req.url == /url_to_be_purged"

Comment: How can we purge URL by pattern, say all matches for /foo/bar/ab*

Answer (score 20):

You don't need to specify scheme for hostname and you may use strict match instead of regex:

```
varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret ban "req.http.host == example.com && req.url == /some/url/"
```

Comment: The other answer had the quote in the wrong place. > varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret "ban req.url == /url_to_be_purged"

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
sudo varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret  -T 127.0.0.1:6082 "ban req.url ~ \"http://example.com/testimage.png$\""
```

worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't add anything but `sudo` to the other answer. This might be better as a comment.

Comment: you saved my day! To solve it is necessary to consider the slashes before the quotes

Comment: The difference for me was the idea of using the `$` in the regex to ensure no other URLs containing the one to clear gets wiped out. The other answer requires you know the domain to clear. For me I don't know the domain, just the URI fragment so this method works well for me.